# Regex taking long time to find a match

Tags: c#, regex

This regex:

```
@"^(?:\s*)((?:[a-zA-Z]+[\s-]?)+[a-zA-Z]+)(?:\s*)$
```

is taking so long time, in some complex cases, it is horrible.

Can you please how can optimize this regex using for C# development in Web Application.

Comment: Your question is too vast. What is the regex supposed to do, it's definition? Also design-patterns is not a correct tag, it is written in it : "Please don't use this tag on questions about text pattern matching" Hah!

Comment: It is quite a clear question actually. And the issue is also quite clear.

Comment: I am trying to Apply RegX,  for  "City" in US.

This needs to prevent from "ReDoS Attack".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `(?:[a-zA-Z]+[\s-]?)+` cause a huge amount of backtracking in your regex as it is placed in between other patterns, the `[\s-]?` matches 1 or **0** whitespaces or `-` (i.e. it is optional) and the whole subpattern gets reduced to `([a-zA-Z]+)+` which causes the [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Use

```
^(?!.{36})\s*([a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*)\s*$
```

instead. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.%7b36%7d%29%5cs*%28%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%5cs-%5d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29*%29%5cs*%24&i=+++look-a+here++++).

**Details**:

- `^`- start of a string
- `(?!.{36})` -  a negative lookahead that will fail the match once its pattern is matched, i.e. if the engine finds any 36 chars other than newline from the start of the string)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
  - `(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `[\s-]` -  a whitespace or `-`
    - `[a-zA-Z]+`  - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `\s*` - 0+ trailing whitespaces
- `$` - end of string (although a `\n` may follow, replace with `\z` if not desired)

Comment: ^\s*([a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*)\s*$        this regex is validating our requirement, but i need to put one more validation in this "max character allowed = 35".
can put limit on total character along with keeping these all validation.
Ex:-  I need to put validation max character till 35.

Comment: @DevKantKumar Yes, right after `^`, add `(?!.{36})` to allow up to and including 35 chars in the string.

Comment: @DevKantKumar Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you.

Comment: :- 
Now this  
 (?!.{36}) 


can u please explain this added regX. .

Comment: Now this (?!.{36})   regx is working.

can u please explain this  regX.  (?!.{36})     as u done earlier as well

Comment: @DevKantKumar I updated the pattern, the regex demo, and the explanation.